# Cisco ASA Static NAT Rule Explanation

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

Here is a chunk of my configuration on my ASA:

```
name <my_external_ip> www.testwebsite.com
object-group service http_https tcp
  port-object eq www
  port-object eq https
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any host www.testwebsite.com object-group http_https
static (DMZ,outside) www.testwebsite.com www.testwebsite.com netmask 255.255.255.255
static (inside,DMZ) www.testwebsite.com www.testwebsite.com netmask 255.255.255.255
```

I am running:
  Cisco ASA Software Version 8.0(4)
  ASA 5520 VPN Plus License

This is probably a very easy question to answer but why in the static (in,out) lines did the consultant use the "name" for both entries. How does the ASA know the translated values. What I mean is how does it know the inside IP of www.testwebsite.com if the only thing defined in the name is the external IP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the server bound to that outside address in the DMZ, or does the DMZ use a private address range?

Comment: EDIT: oh, I see what you are asking.  it doesn't know the inside IP...just the external for that name.

Comment: @TheCleaner Yes, I'm mystified as to how it knows the inside IP. The only thing I can imagine is that it resolves the hostname against the inside DNS servers and get's the local hostname.

Answer (score 0):

From that config snippet, the ASA is not performing NAT.  So the outside IP = inside IP.

Comment: That's my assumption, I just needed to hear someone say it. I'm still intrigued with the code snippet. I'm going to dig a little deeper and see if I can't find anything else.